# Creating a virtual video device, processing signal and redirecting it to physical output on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video, screen, gpu-driver

In Ubuntu 14.4, I need to apply some video processing to the whole screen for a project I'm working on. I want to do the following:

- Create a virtual video output that Ubuntu detects as a second screen attached to the system (like it was an extra HDMI-like interface)
- Capture the video signal from this video interface and apply some basic processing to it.
- Redirect the processed signal to a physical HDMI port to display on a real device.

**Is it there a way to do this in Ubuntu, or any other way to achieve the same results?**

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind of on-the-fly video-editing you want to do, the easiest way to do this would be to transcode on the fly...

Let's say that you want to add a simple watermark onto a video, then you take the video, stream it, capture the stream, add the watermark and re-stream it. 
(off course above example is so simple that you can just do it with the existing filters inside VLC, but you get the point)

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask